# Discord.js - Secretly getting user input

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a 2-player rock-paper-scissors game using Discord.js.

Sadly the Discord API is really slow and afaik doesn't provide any type of middleware. When someone chooses their shape, the other person sees the reaction (or chat message) for quite a while until the bot deletes it, therefore ruining the whole game.

The only way of secretly getting an input I could think of, was sending the user a message in private chat, to which he can react. But having to switch from the server to private chat and then back to the server just makes the game unplayable in my opinion. It's just too much work for the user, compared to simply clicking a reaction.

Another option would be sending a message in the chat, which only a specific user can see. It could say something like "1 = Scissors, 2 = Rock, 3 = Paper". (The mapping would be randomized for each player). The user then picks the corresponding reaction from the options 1, 2 and 3.
But it seems, Discord does not allow to send a message in chat, which only a specific user can see. Or is there a way?

And is there any way of secetly getting user-input without the user having to switch chats?

Does the API maybe provide any kind of middle-ware for messages or reactions which I have overlooked?

Comment: If possible, maybe requiring two bots, you could have one set the reaction options, and then the other could randomly cycle between selecting the reactions and deselecting them. That would probably make it difficult enough for the other player to notice which one was selected, though not completely impossible.
Would be a lot of effort tho for not a whole lot of use.

Comment: @TomGionfriddo I had that idea too, haha!
But it requires two bots, so it's sadly not a solution I'd take. I don't think it's possible using a single bot, as you can only react with each reaction once.

Comment: Could you get them to lock their answer in within a spoiler tag, like this ||r||, and then have the bot delete it asap. Again, prone to intentional cheating, but for a casual game, good enough?

Comment: Another way would be get the bot to add other reactions itself. Eg the user picked rock, the bot also adds reaction to scissors and paper?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Discord does not allow to send a message in chat, which only a specific user can see. Or is there a way?

No, there isn't. Discord API doesn't allow you to specify users that can see a specific guild message.

> And is there any way of secetly getting user-input without the user having to switch chats?

There definitely is!

You could use a fairly new feature, **buttons**. Below is an example code, you can use to base your game on. Things left to implement are:

- Gamestate, e.g. who is on turn, who has how much points, etc.
- Update gamestates (identify gamestate by id?) in the `interactionCreate` event's callback.
- Showing the gamestate to the players, e.g. updating the original message.
- Don't allow players to modify the gamestate of other playing pairs.
- Let the user specify an opponent in `!createGame` command.
- The actual game logic (determining who won, who gets a point, etc.)

That is all I can think of for now. Take those more of a suggestions than requirements. There is no boundary to ones creativity.

```js
// ... Some object to store the gamestates in? ...

client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
  
    // Don't reply to bots
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    // Basic command handler, just for showcasing the buttons
    if (message.content.startsWith("!createGame")) {

        // ... Probably some argument handling for the opponent (e.g. a mention) ...

        // Create an action row component with buttons attached to it
        const actionRow = new Discord.MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                [["Rock", ""], ["Paper", ""], ["Scissors", "✂️"]].map((buttonProperties) => {
                    return new Discord.MessageButton()
                        .setStyle("PRIMARY")
                        .setLabel(buttonProperties[0])
                        .setEmoji(buttonProperties[1])
                        .setCustomId(`rpsgame_${buttonProperties[0].toLowerCase()}`);
                })
            );

        // Send the game message/playground
        message.channel.send({
            content: "Rock, Paper and Scissors: The game!",
            components: [actionRow]
        });
        
    }

});
```

To handle the button clicks, we use the `interactionCreate` event.

```js
client.on("interactionCreate", (interaction) => {
    // If the interaction is a button
    if (interaction.isButton()) {
        // If the button belongs to our game
        if (interaction.customId.startsWith("rpsgame")) {
            // Log what the user has selected to console, as a test
            console.log(`A user '${interaction.member.user.tag}' selected ${interaction.component.emoji.name}.`);
            // Don't forget to reply to an interaction,
            // otherwise an error will be shown on discord.
            interaction.update("Update GameState...");
        }
    }
});
```

[image]

No one will see what the other users have selected, unless you want them to.

[image]

<sub>Using discord.js `^13.0.1`. If you are on v12, there is a nice package called [`discord-buttons`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-buttons).</sub>

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know about buttons as they are fairly new. Thank you, I will definetly use this!